# Format negative number C#

Tags: c#

I have a variable that when it is smaller that zero it formats the number to -5,650 allowing AllowThousands using comma as separator

however when I try to check the value it throws me an exception... what can I do?

`if (int.Parse("-5,650", NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign) < 0)`

The exception string is the next:

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
> at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
> at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
> at System.Int32.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style)
> at Sistema_Caja_Temp_wpf.Vistas.RegistraVentas.btnPagarClick(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\estem\OneDrive\Documents\PROYECTOS\Sistema Caja Temp wpf\Vistas\RegistraVentas.xaml.cs:line 210

Comment: Smaller than what? What number?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the content of `tbVuelto.Text`, you are trying to parse to an `int`.

Comment: sorry, I edited the answer

Comment: @nnaem `int.Parse` takes a `string` as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides going with the "nuclear" option of `NumberStyles.Any`, you can combine `NumberStyles` entries. Good news is that you already know which ones to use.

```
int.Parse("-5,650", NumberStyles.AllowThousands | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign);
// gives "-5650" as an Int32
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your number style to **NumberStyles.Any** and the code you posted succeeds.

Comment: Not work :(

System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Int32.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style)
   at Sistema_Caja_Temp_wpf.Vistas.RegistraVentas.btnPagarClick(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\estem\OneDrive\Documents\PROYECTOS\Sistema Caja Temp wpf\Vistas\RegistraVentas.xaml.cs:line 210

Comment: [Can't reproduce your error](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t58TU1) @EstebanMora, what input did you use? Make a [mre].

Comment: You can try the following: `if (int.Parse("-5,650", NumberStyles.Any) < 0)
Console.WriteLine("true");` interactively [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/tutorials/branches-and-loops?tutorial-step=1), and it works. (Click on the "Enter focus mode" button.)

Answer (score 0):

Integer is only for numbers without a decimal place. If you want to accept numbers with decimal places like in your example you should change your code to `float`, `double` or `decimal`

so if you change your Code to

`if (float.Parse("-5,650") < 0)`

it should work.

if you want to test if your input has the correct format you can use TryParse instead.

like this

```
int input;

if (int.TryParse("-5,650", out input) && input < 0)
```

Comment: I don't think the comma is a decimal separator, it's a thousands-place separator.

Comment: @gunr2171 Oh, I think you're right :) didn't thought about it, at my location we use dots to separate thousands.

Comment: It's not legal to include a comma as a thousands separator when parsing a string to int without explicitly stating that it's allowed. https://dotnetfiddle.net/Rtd9aU

Comment: @gunr2171 yeah i know it was an example for a not supported format